# behavior of C++ ofstream in the event of program crash

Tags: c++, windows, stream, file-handling, ofstream

I am trying to debug a run time error that is causing my program to freeze up in the middle of execution. I have created a logging system that writes a simple log text file during the course of execution.

I write information to the log file simply using an ofstream object's stream insertion (<<) operator with messages of std::string type.

```
void foo(){
// ... Code block 1 ...
// myLogger.Write (timestamp, "Code block1 successfully executed");
// ... Code block 2 ... PROGRAM FREEZE AND CRASH!
}
```

My question is this : Suppose my program freezes up, and I need to kill it's process from the Task Manager, can I trust my logging system to have reliably written all messages prior to the point of crash?

Or, in reference to the above mentioned code, if Code block2 causes my program to freeze up, can I trust that the "Code block1 successfully executed" message will in every case indeed show up in my log file?

P.S. I am on Windows, and the reason I feel concerned is I don't fully trust the OS behavior around file permissions in odd cases. My program does have read/write permission to the file, but I don't know what odd things can happen during crash. Maybe I am just paranoid, please tell me if so.

Is there a better way to detect what code block the crash happens in?

Comment: "can I trust my logging system to have reliably written all messages prior to the point of crash?" Simply: No. Because buffering.

Comment: You usually can't have any guarantees, what's happening before, after or during a _crash_. Unless you have something like `myLogger.flush()` that will explicitly forcing the output stream written. Though that's usually not wanted for logging system purposes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How do you then determine where inside the code the crash is happening?

Comment: What πάντα ῥεῖ meant with "before: The reason for the crash could be long before the crash itself (chronologically). a) That means that other things before the crash could go wrong because of the real error (like logging). b) Finding the crash is only a part of the process. Sometimes it won´t help at all to find the real error.

Comment: The best control you can hope for is [`flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush).  Outside of the C++ standard library you could consider bypassing the filesystem cache.  These typically introduce heavy burdens (aligned memory, aligned writes, not portable) that make it not worthwhile.

Comment: @user3670482 Use `try`/`catch()` blocks to catch regular exceptions, install signal handlers for irregular ones (e.g. processor FPU exceptions).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have try catch blocks, I write to my log file from inside of them. I cant use breakpoints for this code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, would you disagree with arcomber's then?

Comment: @user3670482 Well, `flush()` might fail, if you've been hitting some undefined behavior, or out of memory condition before.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, why is flush() undesirable for logging? I read that flush returns error values (badbit and failbit) in event of failure, I suppose I could use this to detect failure of flush.

Comment: @user3670482 _"why is flush() undesirable for logging?"_ Because it could fairly well change the behavior of your program flow, as it introduces synchronization (blocking writes), and that makes it hard to detect race conditions in multithreaded applications, which could disappear if logging is switched on vs. logging switched off.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ UB causes time-travel: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx

Comment: @Deduplicator Nice link ;) ...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the insights, it was very educational. However, looks like I have some tough time ahead debugging this crash :(

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, If flush fails, do you think the stream will be go into fail state? I was thinking that may be simply checking a stream failure might suffice to catch flush() failure. As in, if (!myStream.fail())

Comment: @user3670482 _"If flush fails, do you think the stream will be go into fail state? ..."_ The situations I'm talking about, are that you might not have guarantees for anything working correctly. You can't even rely on `myStream.fail()` giving you a correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"can I trust that the "Code block1 successfully executed" message will in every case indeed show up in my log file?"*

No, you can't trust that anything is finally written to your log files, when that statement is executed, and your program actually is in some kind of exceptional state.

With a `flush()` call implied with the line to write, chances get better, but still won't be guaranteed. It depends on the exceptional condition your program has met.

Consider a case, your program crashes because of undefined behavior, that accidentally messed up something in the buffers or data used by your `Logger` class instance. Also if you've hit kind of *out of memory* conditions, no guarantees could be given for subsequently executed code, even if it was caught correctly.

---

Also note:
Synchronous flushing usually isn't wanted for logging systems in multithreaded application contexts. The synchronous call of `flush()` might change the actually applied threads' behavior, and hide/obfuscate race conditions, that would appear as soon logging is switched off.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that your text has been written to the log file you need to use std::endl which performs a flush which writes any buffers used to the output device.

Eg:

```
std::cout << "write me!\n";  // no flush

std::cout << "write me!" << std::endl;  // buffer flushed
```

Comment: _"If you want to be sure ..."_ Flushing doesn't make that really reliable, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Provided your process hasn't crashed then flushing the output stream will write the text out will it not?

Comment: Yes in case of _no crash_ or exceptional program state `flush()` or `endl` will force the text is written. But that wasn't in question.